# Change the number format of PercentRank function output

Tags: excel, vba, macros

When I use the PercentRank function, the message box spits out the number in a "0.00" number format.  Is there any way to change that?  Preferably have it come out as "00%"

```
x = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(relevant_Array, answer, 2)
            If x > 0.7 Then MsgBox "WARNING: Price is more than 20% above the average price:  " & x
            If x < 0.3 Then MsgBox "WARNING: Price is more than 20% below the average price:  " & x
            If x > 0.3 And x < 0.7 Then MsgBox "Carry on: your price seems to be accurate: " & x
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried VBA's [Format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx)?

```
 If x > 0.7 Then MsgBox "WARNING: Price is more than 20% above the average price:  " & Format(x, "00%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this...

```
 If x > 0.7 Then MsgBox "WARNING: Price is more than 20% above the average price:  " & Round(x*100,0) & ''%''
```